# Perfect forwarding and dll export

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, dllexport, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to use perfect forwarding on my custom vector class (to mimic the std::vector "emplace_back" in a sense) and to export it from the dll it is defined in.

- **repeated_ptr_field.hpp**

  ```
   template<typename TMessage>
   class RepeatedPtrField
   {
   private:
       std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TMessage>> v_;

   public:
       RepeatedPtrField(const RepeatedPtrField& other) = delete;
       RepeatedPtrField& operator=(const RepeatedPtrField& other) = delete;
       RepeatedPtrField();

       // Some things...

       TMessage* Add()
       {
           // This one is ok so far
           v_.push_back(std::make_unique<TMessage>());
           return v_.back().get();
       }

       template <typename ...Args>
       TMessage* Add(Args&& ...args)
       {
           // This one is giving me headaches
           v_.push_back(std::make_unique<TMessage>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
           return v_.back().get();
       }

       // Some other things...
   };
  ```
- **repeated_ptr_field.cpp**

  ```
   template __declspec(dllexport) Value* RepeatedPtrField<Value>::Add(double&&, Currency&&, long&&);
  ```
- **value.hpp**

  ```
   class Value : public Message
   {
       // Some things...

   public:
       // Both constructors defined in .cpp
       __declspec(dllexport) Value();
       __declspec(dllexport) Value(double value, Currency ccy, long timestamp); // This is the constructor that should be used by the Add(args...) method.

       // Some other things...
   };
  ```

And I'm getting the compiler error: ***'Value::Value': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments***

Comment: OT: Having a `repeated_ptr_field.cpp` could cause you other problems: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Are you sure you actually implemented `Value::Value(double, Currency, long)` and not just declared it inside the header? Could you make the example more replicable? For me [this works](https://onlinegdb.com/ByPdaRBDd) without `__declspec(dllexport`.